# MySQL SUM of one column, DISTINCT of ID column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a summary report of our orders but having trouble extracting all my required data in a single query.

The data I'd like to extract:

- subtotal - SUM of all sale prices
- delivery total - SUM of all orders deliveryTotal
- orders - COUNT of DISTINCT orderIds
- quantity - SUM of all quantity ordered

Orders table (simplified for this example)

```
| orderId | deliveryTotal | total |
|---------|---------------|-------|
| 1       | 5             | 15    |
| 2       | 5             | 15    |
| 3       | 7.50          | 27.50 |
```

Order items table

```
| orderItemId | orderId | productId | salePrice | quantity |
|-------------|---------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 1           | 1       | 1         | 10        | 1        |
| 2           | 2       | 1         | 10        | 1        |
| 3           | 3       | 1         | 10        | 1        |
| 4           | 3       | 2         | 10        | 1        |
```

My current query for extracting this data is

```
SELECT
    SUM(i.salePrice * i.quantity) as subtotal,
    SUM(DISTINCT o.deliveryTotal) as deliveryTotal,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderId) as orders,
    SUM(i.quantity) as quantity
FROM orderItems i
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.orderId = i.orderId
```

Which results in a correct subtotal, order count and quantity sum. But delivery total is returned as 12.50 when I'm after 17.50. If I do `SUM(o.deliveryTotal)` it will return 25.

EDIT: Desired results

```
| subtotal | deliveryTotal | orders | quantity |
|----------|---------------|--------|----------|
| 40.00    | 17.50         | 3      | 4        |
```

Comment: Can you give SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @Sadikhasan here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02cb0/1

Comment: Updated question with desired results

Comment: Will this query always be applied across the whole table, or do you expect to be adding a `GROUP BY` later?

Comment: Always the whole table (will have a where statement in to select between dates) but no grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the join, the `SUM(DISTINCT deliveryTotal)` aggregate is being applied to a rowset including the values `5, 5, 7.5, 7.5` (distinct `5 + 7.5 = 12.5`).

The rows your `SUM()` acted on become more apparent if you simply do

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orderItems i
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.orderId = i.orderId
```

Instead you are asking for the `SUM()` of all the values in `deliveryTotal`, irrespective of their position in the join with `orderItems`. That means you need to apply the aggregate at a different level.

Since you are not intending to add a `GROUP BY` later, the easiest way to do that is to use a subselect whose purpose is only to get the `SUM()` across the whole table.

```
SELECT
    SUM(i.salePrice * i.quantity) as subtotal,
    -- deliveryTotal sum as a subselect
    (SELECT SUM(deliveryTotal) FROM orders) as deliveryTotal,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderId) as orders,
    SUM(i.quantity) as quantity
FROM orderItems i
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.orderId = i.orderId
```

Subselects are usually discouraged but there won't be a significant performance penalty for the subselect, none different from the alternative methods of using a join for it. The calculation has to be done on a separate aggregate from the existing join no matter what.  Other methods would place a subquery `CROSS JOIN` in the `FROM` clause, which performs the same thing we placed here in the subselect. Performance would be the same.

Comment: (SQLfiddle isn't responding for me right now to post the verified result, but I loaded it in my test database and it does indeed work)

Answer (score 18):

https://tiaashish.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/mysql-sum-for-distinct-rows-with-left-join/

Here is a blog post that shows exactly what I was looking for. Maybe this can help others too.

The formula is something like this:

`SUM(o.deliveryTotal) * COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderId) / COUNT(*)`

Comment: This seems indeed like the answer OP was looking for

Comment: Excellent and is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but this seems to give the incorrect result. The answer should be `5 + 5 + 7.50 = 17.50`, but this returns `(5 + 5 + 7.50 + 7.50) * 3 / 4 = 18.75`.

Comment: @ClintWinter, then you probably have 2 rows of `7.50` if it adds it twice.

Comment: awesome!  shot and  elegant!

Comment: This is simply incorrect. How does this have the most upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Select per Order in the Inner Select and than sum it up

```
Select 
SUM(subtotal) as subtotal,
sum(deliveryTotal) as deliveryTotal,
count(1) as orders,
sum(quantity) as quantity
from (
SELECT 
    SUM(i.salePrice * i.quantity) as subtotal,
    o.deliveryTotal as deliveryTotal,
    SUM(i.quantity) as quantity
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderItems i ON o.orderId = i.orderId
group by o.orderId) as sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query results exactly what you need

```
SELECT SUM(conctable.subtotal),
SUM(conctable.deliveryTotal),
SUM(conctable.orders),
SUM(conctable.quantity) from  
(SELECT SUM(i.salePrice * i.quantity) as subtotal,
    o.deliveryTotal as deliveryTotal,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderId) as orders,
    SUM(i.quantity) as quantity
FROM orderItems i
JOIN orders o ON o.orderId = i.orderId group by i.orderid) as conctable;
```