# SUN ignores DISTINCT in query between two tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm making a query between two tables `ordem_servico(1) -> fluxo_servico_time(n)` and in this query I need to give a SUN in the ordem_servico.cm_total column, but as I have a join in this table the result of the SUN always counts the extra, ignoring my distinct

**Table ordem_servico**

| id | finalizado | data_encerrado | status | cm_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | 2024-02-10 10:59:50 | true | 500.0 |
| 2 | true | 2024-02-10 10:59:50 | true | 1320.0 |
| 3 | true | 2024-02-10 10:59:50 | true | 1188.0 |
| 4 | true | 2024-02-10 10:59:50 | true | 1320.0 |

**Table fluxo_servico_time**

| id | ordem_servico_id | user_id | tipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | play |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | play |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | play |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | play |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | play |
| 6 | 4 | 5 | play |
| 7 | 1 | 5 | play |

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id) as qtd_os,
  fluxo_servico_times.user_id,
  SUM(sub.total_cm) AS total_cm
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ordem_servicos.id,
      SUM(ordem_servicos.cm_total) AS total_cm
    FROM
      ordem_servicos
    WHERE
      ordem_servicos.data_encerrado >= '2024-02-01 00:00:00 -0300'
      AND ordem_servicos.data_encerrado < '2024-02-29 23:59:59 -0300'
      AND ordem_servicos.finalizado = true
      AND ordem_servicos.status = true
    GROUP BY
      ordem_servicos.id
  ) AS sub
  INNER JOIN fluxo_servico_times ON fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id = sub.id
WHERE
  fluxo_servico_times.tipo = 'play'
  AND fluxo_servico_times.user_id = 5
GROUP BY
  fluxo_servico_times.user_id
```

Query result: qty: 4 user ID: 5, total CM: **6648.0**

Apparently he is ignoring the DISTINCT in this part of the query `COUNT(DISTINCT flow_servico_times.ordem_servico_id)` and adding the same value several times, the correct value is **4328**

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result? I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: You are not using any `distinct`s in your `SUM()`. You only `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL SUM of one column, DISTINCT of ID column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202233/mysql-sum-of-one-column-distinct-of-id-column)

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question seems to imply you expect the distinct to clear up all "duplicate" records generated from the fanning.  Queries don't work this way.  Distinct only applies to the function (Count) using the distinct or all the selected rows if used "Select distinct column1, column2...) So the sum (SUN?)  would never work the way I think you're expecting.   And even if you put distinct on the sum, if you have multiple records with the same value in your base table (1320 for example) it would cause those records to be reduced down to one, which you do not want.

To achieve what I believe you desire:

OPTION 1)
If we can assume you just want the sum of cm_total for all records from ordem_servicos for the limiting date range and status/finalizado...  then we can just add the sum to every record on the sub query using a window function and partitioning by null.  This basically says sum totals based on the where clause and put that total on each row.  if we partitied by something besides "null" the system would sum within each set.

Currently your outer query is causing the values to be fanned or (multiplied due to the cardinality) and then the outer sum is returning the wrong result.  To work around it we simply get the sum in the inner query and then do not sum in the outer; and since total_cm is not used in an aggregrate, we have to group by the total_cm.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-yKWBnai)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id) as qtd_os,
  fluxo_servico_times.user_id,
  total_cm
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ordem_servicos.id,
      sum(cm_total) over (partition by null) as total_cm
    FROM ordem_servicos
    WHERE
      ordem_servicos.data_encerrado >= '2024-02-01 00:00:00 -0300'
      AND ordem_servicos.data_encerrado < '2024-02-29 23:59:59 -0300'
      AND ordem_servicos.finalizado = true
      AND ordem_servicos.status = true
      AND Exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM  fluxo_servico_times 
                  WHERE fluxo_servico_times.tipo = 'play'
                    AND fluxo_servico_times.user_id = 5
                    AND fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id = ordem_servicos.id)
  ) AS sub
  INNER JOIN fluxo_servico_times ON fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id = sub.id
WHERE
  fluxo_servico_times.tipo = 'play'
  AND fluxo_servico_times.user_id = 5
GROUP BY
  fluxo_servico_times.user_id,
  sub.total_cm
```

Option 2)
Since the fanning (record multiplication) from the 2nd table is causing the issue, and you're not using any of the values which cause it to fan, you could select distinct from fluxo table before you join.  Thus creating a 1:1 relationship so the total_Cm can't fan out; and then your sum(total_cm) will work.

[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/g7ArCDuA)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id) as qtd_os,
  fluxo_servico_times.user_id,
  sum(cm_total) as cm_total
  FROM ordem_servicos
INNER JOIN (SELECT Distinct ordem_Servico_id, user_id
              FROM fluxo_servico_times 
             WHERE tipo = 'play'
               AND user_id = 5) fluxo_servico_times
   ON fluxo_servico_times.ordem_servico_id = ordem_servicos.id
WHERE
      ordem_servicos.data_encerrado >= '2024-02-01 00:00:00 -0300'
      AND ordem_servicos.data_encerrado < '2024-02-29 23:59:59 -0300'
      AND ordem_servicos.finalizado = true
      AND ordem_servicos.status = true
GROUP BY fluxo_servico_times.user_id
```

Either way Resutling in:

```
+--------+---------+----------+
| qtd_os | user_id | total_cm |
+--------+---------+----------+
|      4 |       5 |   4328.0 |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Which matches the desired results provided: (assuming those are the desired results)

Query result: qty: 4 user ID: 5, total CM: 6648.0

with total CM: now equaling 4328 instead of 6648

Comment: This query returned a total of 15548.0, but I don't understand what this value is coming from

Comment: You must have data not being represented in the data set provided; both demos report exactly 4328. total_cm.  In demo 1 are you certain the "sub" query returns the correct total?  if it doen' then your where clause isn't correct.  in the 2nd demo; I can't see how it would ever be wrong since we get to a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: 1st option corrected: https://dbfiddle.uk/-yKWBnai  We needed to check for only records in the set defined by your where clause for play and user 5.https://dbfiddle.uk/-yKWBnai  Option 2 is simplier as we can avoid the redundant where clause

Comment: That's right, you needed to check if there is a "play" for user "5" in the "morfo_servico_times" table within the subquery because without this check it was giving the SUM in "ordem_servicos" for other users, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AndreiBrayer  so did option 1 or 2 meet the expecations? if so please close out the quesiton or indicate what aspects are yet incorrect.

Comment: option 1 and 2 are the same, I believe you repeated the link, but option 1 works perfectly, but there are cases in which I will not have the fluxo_servico_times.user_id, and if this filter does not exist it will add all the ordem_servicos, I needed that if the fluxo_servico_times.user_id clause does not exist, it should be separated by users, remembering that several users may have worked in the same order, and this order must be accounted for for all users.

Comment: I solved it the following way [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/04sVRcId), I don't know if it's the best solution available but this way, if I don't have a **user_id** it brings me everything grouped by users, and if I have a **user_id** it filters correctly too